# Clear ParseFile cache

Tags: caching, parse-platform

My app allows users to download files that were uploaded to my parse server by other users.

When downloading a file, it is written on the device, as it's often something that the user might want to print later, or send to another user.

The problem is that every ParseFile that is downloaded via "getDataInBackground" is also cached, so after a while, the cache size is like 50mb for a 1mb app.
Is there any way to clear the cache? Or even better, tell the API that I don't need any cache at all?

Comment: I'm not sure that the app is caching by itself the images. When you close the app from the background and you open it, does it download the images again? You can check it our from "Network" in xcode

Comment: I'm actually using Android and these are not images. If I close the app, open it, and try to download a file, they are instantly available, because they are cached. 
Also, I can see in the cache size in the phone settings, and it's getting bigger each time I download a file.

Comment: Oh sorry i thought you were using iOS... I'm not familiar with Android. Good luck :)